# Is there a way to mute all sounds when placing a call using Twilio?

Tags: node.js, twilio

I have a button that controls placing outbound calls using twilio. However, when the user clicks the button there is a sound that plays and then phone ringing plays after. I was wondering if there was a way for the user to press that button and no sound would play?

Comment: its a good practice to postyour code, so that people can help your efficiently

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the [Twilio Client](https://www.twilio.com/client)? There are some parameters you can set that modify the sounds generated by the client itself.

[Available Sound Properties](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/device#available-sound-properties)

Comment: I am using Twilio client. Is there a different way where the browser doesn't act like a phone, but instead just places the outbound call? Or do I have to use Twilio client and then get rid of all the sounds?

Comment: Twilio client is the correct approach. Try what I provided above and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you just want your web application to start a phone call without connecting the user in the browser (as you have suggested in your comments) then you don't actually want to use Twilio Client.

Instead, you should [use the Twilio REST API to start a phone call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource). Your browser application should send a request to your server and your server should then call the REST API to start a call.

An example of starting a phone call from Node.js is below:

```js
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.calls
      .create({
         url: 'https://example.com/voice,
         to: TO_NUMBER,
         from: YOUR_TWILIO_NUMBER
       })
      .then(call => console.log(call.sid));
```

When you call that code Twilio will place the outbound call to `TO_NUMBER`. When that call connects, Twilio will make a webhook request to the `url` which should respond with [TwiML to tell Twilio what to do next with the call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml).

Check out the documentation on [making calls with Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/make-calls) for more.